# Unexpected 404 Not Found Error in Laravel (5.8)

Tags: laravel-routing

I have these lines in api.php

```
Route::apiResources([
    'users' => 'Api\UserController',
    'products' => 'Api\ProductController',
    'categories' => 'Api\CategoryController',
]);

Route::get('/users/custom1', 'Api\UserController@custom1');
```

When I have them in this order and I call the route I get 404 Not Found.

But when I change the order, I get result:

```
Route::get('/users/custom1', 'Api\UserController@custom1');

Route::apiResources([
    'users' => 'Api\UserController',
    'products' => 'Api\ProductController',
    'categories' => 'Api\CategoryController',
]);
```

This situation has frustrated me because I thought the error originated from the model and find method:

```
public function custom1()
{
    $user2 = User::find(2);

    return $user2;
}
```

Because I was checking the result in Postman and it shows the error like this when you ask for application/json as response:

```
{
    "message": "No query results for model [App\\User] custom1",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\laravel-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
    "line": 204,
    "trace": [
        {...
```

What is the reason of this change?

Because in both situations I can see the route in route:list.

Comment: Please share more details - what do you mean by "call the route"? What have you tried to debug that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have realized the reason when I checked route:list with a clearer mind.

[image]

Laravel shows route:list in alphabetical order but actually the order we write in route file matters right?

So, it occured to me that if this line is coming first:

[image]

Laravel is trying to use custom1 as a route parameter.

So I must define this specific route before api resource routes:

```
Route::get('/users/custom1', 'Api\UserController@custom1');

Route::apiResources([
    'users' => 'Api\UserController',
    'products' => 'Api\ProductController',
    'categories' => 'Api\CategoryController',
]);
```